# How do I save the values of my variables in my while loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying my best to get through a C++ online class and I'm currently writing a program to help a local restaurant automate its breakfast billing system. The program should do the following:

A. Show the customer the different breakfast items offered by the restaurant.

B. Allow the customer to select more than one item from the menu.

C. Calculate and print the bill.

Assume that the restaurant offers the following breakfast items (the price of each item is shown to the right of the item):

```
            Plain Egg 1.45
            Bacon & Egg 2.45
            Muffin 0.99
            French Toast 1.99
            Fruit Basket 2.49
            Cereal 0.69
            Coffee 0.50
            Tea 0.75
```

My code is at the bottom, my problem is with the while loop in the showMenu function.  As an example say the user wants to order a Plain Egg. Then it will run line 104 orderTotal = menuList[0].menuPrice + orderTotal. That should mean 0 = 1.45 + 0 right? Afterwards it runs orderTax = orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax. Which should mean 0 = 1.45 * 0.05 + 0 if I'm correct? My trouble is that both my orderTotal and orderTax remain at 0 when I cout << them. What can I do to fix this? I also know that my menuPrice variable is working because it displays their values on the menu. Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType
{

    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;

};

void getData(menuItemType menuList[]);
void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[], double orderTotal, double orderTax, int orderCount[]);
void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[], double orderTotal, double orderTax, int orderCount[]);

int main()
{

    menuItemType menuList[8];
    double orderTotal = 0;
    double orderTax = 0;
    int orderCount[8]{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

    getData(menuList);
    showMenu(menuList, orderTotal, orderTax, orderCount);
    printCheck(menuList, orderTotal, orderTax, orderCount);

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[]) // This function's purpose is to fill the array menuList[8] with the name and price of each item.
{

    menuItemType plainEgg;
    menuItemType baconEgg;
    menuItemType muffin;
    menuItemType frenchToast;
    menuItemType fruitBasket;
    menuItemType cereal;
    menuItemType coffee;
    menuItemType tea;

    plainEgg.menuItem = "Plain Egg";
    plainEgg.menuPrice = 1.45;
    baconEgg.menuItem = "Bacon & Egg";
    baconEgg.menuPrice = 2.45;
    muffin.menuItem = "Muffin";
    muffin.menuPrice = 0.99;
    frenchToast.menuItem = "French Toast";
    frenchToast.menuPrice = 1.99;
    fruitBasket.menuItem = "Fruit Basket";
    fruitBasket.menuPrice = 2.49;
    cereal.menuItem = "Cereal";
    cereal.menuPrice = 0.69;
    coffee.menuItem = "Coffee";
    coffee.menuPrice = 0.50;
    tea.menuItem = "Tea";
    tea.menuPrice = 0.75;

    menuList[0] = plainEgg;
    menuList[1] = baconEgg;
    menuList[2] = muffin;
    menuList[3] = frenchToast;
    menuList[4] = fruitBasket;
    menuList[5] = cereal;
    menuList[6] = coffee;
    menuList[7] = tea;

}

void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[], double orderTotal, double orderTax, int orderCount[]) // This function's purpose is to display the menu to the user for orders and calculate the total.
{
    //Displays menu
    cout << "\t" << "Welcome to Johnny's Restaurant" << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "What would you like to order?" << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "1. " <<menuList[0].menuItem << setw(10) << "$" << menuList[0].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "2. " <<menuList[1].menuItem << setw(8) << "$" << menuList[1].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "3. " <<menuList[2].menuItem << setw(13) << "$" << menuList[2].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "4. " <<menuList[3].menuItem << setw(7) << "$" << menuList[3].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "5. " <<menuList[4].menuItem << setw(7) << "$" << menuList[4].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "6. " <<menuList[5].menuItem << setw(13) << "$" << menuList[5].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "7. " <<menuList[6].menuItem << setw(13) << "$" << menuList[6].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "8. " <<menuList[7].menuItem << setw(16) << "$" << menuList[7].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    bool orderActive = true; {};
    int itemChoice;

    //Prompts the user to pick from the menu
    while (orderActive == true)
    {

        cout << "Select the number pertaining to which item you would like or press [0] to finish: ";
        cin >> itemChoice;
        if (itemChoice == 1)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[0].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTax = orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[0] = orderCount[0] + 1;
            cout << menuList[0].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 2)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[1].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTax = orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[1] = orderCount[1] + 1;
            cout << menuList[1].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 3)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[2].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTax = orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[2] = orderCount[2] + 1;
            cout << menuList[2].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 4)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[3].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTax = orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[3] = orderCount[3] + 1;
            cout << menuList[3].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 5)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[4].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[4] = orderCount[4] + 1;
            cout << menuList[4].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 6)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[5].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[5] = orderCount[5] + 1;
            cout << menuList[5].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 7)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[6].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[6] = orderCount[6] + 1;
            cout << menuList[6].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;

        }
        else if (itemChoice == 8)
        {
            orderTotal = menuList[7].menuPrice + orderTotal;
            orderTotal * 0.05 + orderTax;
            orderCount[7] = orderCount[7] + 1;
            cout << menuList[7].menuItem << " has been added to your order." << endl;
    
        }
        else if (itemChoice == 0)
        {
            orderActive = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error Try Again" << endl;
        }
            
    }

    cout << endl;
    }

    void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[], double orderTotal, double orderTax, int orderCount[]) // This function's purpose is to display the user's total
    {

    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "Welcome to Johnny's Restaurant" << endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        if (orderCount[0] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[0] << setw(10) << menuList[0].menuItem << setw(15) << "$" << menuList[0].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[1] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[1] << setw(12) << menuList[1].menuItem << setw(13) << "$" << menuList[1].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[2] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[2] << setw(7) << menuList[2].menuItem << setw(18) << "$" << menuList[2].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[3] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[3] << setw(13) << menuList[3].menuItem << setw(12) << "$" << menuList[3].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[4] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[4] << setw(13) << menuList[4].menuItem << setw(12) << "$" << menuList[4].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[5] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[5] << setw(7) << menuList[5].menuItem << setw(18)<< "$" << menuList[5].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[6] > 0)
        {
            cout << "\t" << orderCount[6] << setw(7) << menuList[6].menuItem << setw(18) << "$" << menuList[6].menuPrice << endl;
        }
        if (orderCount[7] > 0)
        {
        cout << "\t" << orderCount[7] << setw(4) << menuList[7].menuItem << setw(21) << "$" << menuList[7].menuPrice << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << "\t" << "Tax " << setw(22) << "$" << orderTax << endl;
    cout << "\t" << "Amount Due: " << setw(14) << "$" << orderTotal << endl;


}
```

Comment: please read about [mcve]. For an issue about adding and mulitplying some numbers I would expect a complete example in not more than 10 lines. Not only helps this us to help you, but also you should rather focus on one issue rather than >100 lines of code when only 2-3 of them matter

Comment: You have to pass the parameters by references instead of values.

Comment: You urgently need to trim this code down. Remove *anything* not necessary to illustrate the problem. One thing that would help *considerably* is **learn about `for` loops and how to iterate over arrays**. That sprawling mess of `if` statements is a cry for help.

Comment: As Quimby said. You pass the parameters in your function as value. So all modifications in the function will be lost. You need to pass the arguments by reference like so: ````double& orderTotal, double& orderTax```` Then it will work. And then you should refactor your code and use C++ language elements. It will help a lot, when you do that. Start with: Do never use C-Style arrays in C++. There is no reason to do so. And, if you use ````std::vector```` or ````std::array```` instead, your code will immediately improve.

Comment: The real beauty of the [mre] is it is a powerful debugging technique. It is hard to make a good one without getting part way in, realizing the solution, and fixing it.